# HTML/URL: How to analyze which URL a button is calling?

Tags: javascript, html, url, search, get

How to know which URL a button is calling, when clicking on it?

For example, if I type `search text` in *google.com*, I can replicate it with calling `google.com/search?q=search+text`

For *wikipedia.com* you do the same with `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=search+text`

I got this information by typing text in the search text fields, clicking the search-buttons and then looking at the resulting urls. I am curious how to get this information, just by looking at the source code itself.

Answer (score 1):

A general answer: to see where a form is taking you, find the opening `form` tag and look at the `action` attribute. Or, if the form is submitted via javascript, look out for event listeners applied to the submit button and possible `ajax` requests in the code.

Taking wikipedia as an example, the form element has `action="//www.wikipedia.org/search-redirect.php"`. This is the page you will be led to when clicking the form's submit button, and for many websites, this might show you what you looking for.

The fact that, on wikipedia, the term `redirect` is in the URL suggests that there is a more complicated process behind searching than simply submitting a form to the straight search results page. This goes on behind the scenes at the server, so it's impossible to tell what's happening just from the source code of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Those examples are `requests method`

- `google.com/search?q=search+text`
- `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=search+text`

There is a code on the backend that tells the application how to handle this `requests`...

You need to understand a little bit of

- `GET` : You will be able to see the request on the URL
- `POST` : You will **not** be able to see the request on the URL

There are a lot of differences... But for this post, I think it´s ok...

### Inspect element and see event listeners tab

Try to inspect the elements of your page ... The shortcut is <kbd>F12</kbd> .

Maybe you can find the requests made...

Try to understand the `event listeners` tab...

Hope that this can help you understand a little bit

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to pass on information or requests from the client to the server, the GET method and the POST method

The GET method involves use of query string which are appended after the script page with key value pairs separated by ampersand "&" that is `www.domain.ext/scriptpage?key1=value1&key2=value2` etc. This is the URL you will usually see when request is being sent (loading) and often even after receiving response from the server. These urls/querystrings are usually embedded in anchors (`<a href>`) tags as hyperlinks or in buttons.

The POST method is mainly declared in the form element along with ACTION keyword which tells the page or the server script to run when the form is submitted. The contents of the form cannot be seen on the url on submission.